# installing downloaded in puppetmaster on nodes

Tags: puppet, configuration-management, ganglia

I am new to Puppet.

I have downloaded a ganglia repo on my puppet master.

How to install this repo on all the nodes?

`Master: ubuntu 14.04`

`Agent: 12.04`

I want to make the puppetmaster server the server for required packages. So that packages can be installed on nodes without internet connectivity

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like [reprepro](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/apt) on your master to set-up the apt repository for ganglia, then use the puppetlabs-apt module to add the apt-repo on your master to all your agents.

There's a [reprepro module](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/jtopjian/reprepro) on the forge that you can probably use to set that up.

So, if your master is called `puppet-master.example.com`, and you set it up as an apt server, you could add some code like this to all your agents:

```
apt::source { 'ganglia-mirror':
  location    => 'http://puppet-master.example.com/aptserver',
  release     => 'dist',
  repos       => 'ganglia',
  include_src => false,
}
```

I'd recommend reading through the documentation on both modules, and you should be able to achieve a Ganglia APT mirror on your Puppet master.

Comment: Do you recommend copying the ganglia package as .deb file from master to agent. And later running dpkg using exec